# How to Fix this error in Angular Application "No provider for ControlContainerAngular"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms

I am using bootstrap-4 in my angular7 application. I want to design my application with bootstrap

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>
```

I expected that there should be  search box as including in bootstrap documentation but the error is  "No provider for ControlContainer Angular"

Comment: have you imported required form modules in @ngmodule ?

Comment: like which one ? every thing working fine like bootstrap navbar , but this generates error

Comment: yes i did import form modules ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the ReactiveFormsModule in your application?

If yes, then you should create a FormGroup and then bind it to your Html

Don't forget to import both ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule in your application.

component.ts file

```
export class MyComponent {
  reactiveForm= new FormGroup({
    reactiveFormControl: new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

html file

```
<form class="form-inline" [formGrop]="reactiveForm">
....
<input type="text" formControlName="reactiveFormControl">
```

Check [ControlContainer documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlContainer)

If it's not fixed, please share tyour module.ts for further investigation.

Comment: Athanasios Kataras Thanks :-) Now Problem is fixed , in particular component i was not importing these dependencies related to forms.

Comment: Really nice to hear this. Don't forget to upvote and accept the responses if they are useful to you.

Comment: Yes sir i did .    Athanasios Kataras